# Finding last Occurence of String in C

Tags: c, string

I want to compare a String in another String like "ther" in "motherfathersister" and the result would be either null ( no match ) or the remaining characters after the last occurence ( in this example) "thersister". 
I have changed the implemantation of strstr from string.h but the result is everytime the same.
Where i have made a mistake?
Thanks

```
char *stRstr(char *s, char *m)
{
    char *last=NULL;
    size_t n = strlen(m);
    while(*s)
    {
        if(!memcmp(s++,m,n))
        {
            last=s-1;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? don't you want the output to be _"thersister"_?

Comment: What exactly does "the result is everytime the same" mean?  Also, you have a bug where you will `memcmp()` past the end of the `s` string, resulting in undefined behavior.  Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Actually I wonder that you do not get a segfault, because you obviously access `s` beyound its bounds (consider what `memcmp` does when `s` points to the last non-`'\0'`-character); Further, I'd change the code such that it scans the string backwards, not forward.

Comment: Also, why not implement this in terms of `strstr()` instead of `memcmp()`? And/or work backwards from the end of the string (so your first match will be the one you want).

Comment: @StephanLechner shouldn't segfault be optional when invoking UB?

Comment: @CIsForCookies: yes, it's optional (actually undefined), but still rather common. Hope OP gets the point anyway.

Comment: I only asked because I tested this code and didn't segfault myself, though I expected it to

Comment: I compiled and run the code and the program returned his expected string `thersister`. Don't know what his problem is?

Comment: @AndreKampling The fact that it is returning the right output does not mean it is correct and cannot blow up at some point. `memcmp` compares `n` bytes starting from `s` (not stopping if it finds the null char). Imagine the case where `s` points at the second-last element and `n` is 10. `memcmp` will definitely access memory that could cause segfault.

Comment: @DavideSpataro: Yes I know, but his question is not about that, he asks why the result is everytime the same. Whatever that mean!?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation wasnt self explanatoried enough. The result is exerytime the first occurence ( like in strstr ) and not the last. i think with the while loop the null pointer to it is prevented, or not ?

Comment: I personally *do* get the result you desire - however, as you have undefined behaviour in your code, *anything* could happen, you could even switch of the sun... Are you aware that there *is* already such a function (str***r***chr)?

Comment: Yes, i am. But strchr stands for character in string, so this functions returns only the last occurence of the character not of the string

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys
I found my mistake...
i didnt't called my function "stRstr" but "strstr"... And this function is already implemented...
Thanks for your help, without your feedback, in terms of that my functions returns the right result, i would have been lost...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your code will access `s` beyond its bounds (consider what memcmp does when s points to the last non-'\0'-character). So I'd get rid of the `memcmp`-usage and I'd scan the string from backwards.

In analogy to `strstr`, which quickly scans the string looking for a single-character match and compares then the rest, see the following code that does exactly the same in a backwards manner.

Hope it helps.

```
const char *stRstr(const char *s, const char *m)
{
    const char* ptr = s + strlen(s);
    size_t mlen = strlen(m);
    while (ptr-- != s) {  // until ptr reaches the beginning of s
        if (*ptr==*m) {   // single character match (first characters of s and m)?
            if (strncmp(ptr,m,mlen)==0)  // check the remainder
                return ptr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void printLast(const char* s) {
    if (s)
        printf("last: %s\n", s);
    else
        printf("string not found.\n");
}
int main() {

    const char* s = "this is the first, this is the last";
    const char* m = "this";

    const char* last = stRstr(s, m);
    printLast(last);

    last = stRstr(s, "not contained");
    printLast(last);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should work (the problem is elsewhere) but it has some issues:

- using `memcmp()` is incorrect as it may access `s` beyond its last element. you should use `strncmp()` instead or add a test on the lengths.
- the posted code would not find the last occurrence of the empty substring and return `NULL`, where it should return a pointer to the trailing null byte.
- for consistency, you should call it `strrstr()` or `my_strrstr()`.

Here is a faster and safer version:

```
char *my_strrstr(const char *s, const char *m) {
    char *last = NULL;
    size_t n = strlen(m);

    while ((s = strchr(s, *m)) != NULL) {
        if (!strncmp(s, m, n))
            last = (char *)s;
        if (*s++ == '\0')
            break;
    }
    return last;
}
```